# Activity Feed Structure

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a function that will add a log of what my user has done into my database so that I can then build a activity feed for other users' activity feed.

What I imagine it to resemble so far.

**Activity table**

```
id | user_id | source | source_id | timestamp
```

**Example Input**

```
1 | 1 | photo_upload | 54 | 1333906150 //54 being the ID of the photo in my DB
2 | 1 | follow | 2 | 1333906159 // 2 being the id of a user
```

This way I can easily pull information from the database for a users activity, `"user_id = {$followers}` then show them according to what their source is e.g show the image for a photo_upload.

**EDIT**
What would be the best way to display different types of the feed.
This is what I currently have but it seems a bit much.

```
<?php
$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE `user_id` IN (".$following.") ORDER BY `id` DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

    switch ($row['source']) {
        case "photoupload":
            // Display photo upload layout
            break;
        case "follow":
            // Display follow layout
            break;
    }

}
?>
```

Does anyone see any ways to improve upon this?

Comment: The most obvious improvement is _NOT_ to use a Unix timestamp, but rather a [proper DATETIME column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: Have you run into any problems so far?

Comment: @Micheal Why would you advise this?

Comment: @Lix i am trying to work out this kinks as i design it rather than during the creation of it.

Comment: It really depends on the specification of the application.

Comment: @Lix Updated with another question

Comment: To me that does not look excessive at all.  You might want to look into caching the results of those queries depending on how much data they return. possibly place limits on the query... Other than that it looks good.

Comment: @Micheal Why? It really depends on application. I like Timestamp more because it stores everything in UTC. Also it is stored as a CPU friendly, 32bit integer. Plain and simple. Possibly the fastest datatype representing time. Some applications may want to store Timezone as well. My apps work in a single timezone so never felt the need for it.

Comment: In the future, you should not really change your question with an edit.  First you were asking about the DB structure and then about displaying the data.  Stick to one question - if you have another - post a new question.

Comment: @lix this question was about the best way to produce a activity feed, I was asking for improvements on my database structure and saying how i could then show it, there for i added how i plan on showing it.

Comment: I guess since there are no answers yet it does not really matter.  But your question **did** change from a DB structure to displaying the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an abstract class describing a feeditem type:

```
abstract class Application_Feed_Item_Abstract {
    protected $_item;

    public function __construct($itemData) {
        $this->_item = $itemData;
    }

    abstract public function render();
}
```

Implement this class for different kinds of content:

```
class Application_Feed_Item_Photo extends Application_Feed_Item_Abstract {
    public function render() {
        //Custom rendering logic for a Photo
        return '<div>Watch my <a href="photo.php?id=' . $this->_item['source_id'] . '">photo</a></div>';
    }
}

class Application_Feed_Item_Follow extends Application_Feed_Item_Abstract {
    public function render() {
        //Custom rendering logic for a Follower
        return '<div>I got a new <a href="photo.php?id=' . $this->_item['source_id'] . '">follower</a></div>';
    }
}
```

So when you pull a record, you are able to create a renderer object on the fly depending on the kind of feeditem:

```
//Pull items from database and store them as an Array or other iterable object.
//Here i assume we call this collection of rows from the database $feeditems

//Mapping of source to renderer classes
$types = array(
    "photoupload" => "Application_Feed_Item_Photo",
    "follow" => "Application_Feed_Item_Request",
    "somethingelse" => "Application_Feed_Item_Somethingelse"
);

//Process every item
foreach($feeditems as $item) {
    $type = $item['source'];
    if(!array_key_exists($type, $types)) {
        throw new Exception("Unsupported feeditem type.");
    }
    $type = $types[$type];

    $renderer = new $type($item);
    echo $renderer->render();
}
```

Just a loose idea for a way to implement it. But as stated by another user, there are many different ways to do it, depending on your requirements. The method you used in your question would work just fine

Comment: I am horribly new to class's and OOP but i am taking a good stab at understanding your code, if you do not hear back from me, send help. But seriously im going to take a while to break this down as it seems perfect!

Comment: can you give me a example of what $feedtypes should look like so i can try out the code in a test enviorment?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat.  Similarly there are many ways to achieve the same results you require.

Some suggestions for "improving" IMO would be -

**1. Fetching this data as pre-generated HTML with an AJAX call.**

Using an AJAX call once the page is loaded, you could have your server build the HTML segments of your users activity feed.  This will allow your page to load much faster and your content will be loaded shortly after.

You don't even have to build HTML on the server - you could also pass a JSON object back from the AJAX call and build your HTML with JavaScript.

**2. Creating a cached static HTML file of the users feed that is simply included into the markup.**

You could have your server generate all the HTML needed for a users feed at a certain interval - every 30 minutes for example - and then save that HTML into a file to be included in the existing HTML.  You can do this using PHP's `include()` function.

Using this method the activity feed will have a delay when refreshing so it might not be the best option - but if you make the interval smaller - every 5 minutes for example, you'll be saving a lot of calls to the DB.

Check out [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) - you could possibly use them to schedule the updates.

**3. Place an `index` on the `user_id` field in your DB since you are using it to search by user.**

This is a very important one especially if you are expecting many entries to exist in your DB.  Placing an index on the fields that you use to search a table will vastly increase the performance of your queries.

---

I'm sure there are many more things that can be suggested here.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the first two in depth a bit more? They seem interesting.

Comment: Thank you Lix. But their is going to be differences between how the followers div will look like compared to the photo_upload div for example
http://gyazo.com/547240b6fd37ca8df7f2dbbfb3c4ff2e
See how they look differently? When i generate the page how can i make it so that if source = photo_upload it displays like that and for follows it displays like the top one?

Comment: So then consider the first option.  This way you just check to see who exactly is requesting the data and give them the correct HTML

Comment: So you are advising when the page is loaded i make a ajax call to a file which will generate the html files within, lets say /stored/activty/activity_1.html then display if needed?

Comment: Exactly!  You'll also need to know who is making the request so that you can give them the correct content.

Comment: What if someone then changes their name? I would have to delete the file and remake it?

Comment: Well when you generate the HTML from the AJAX call you don't need to save it to the system - just send it as the response to the request.